# Remove slashes from Start and end of the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, slash

I have a URL like :

```
var folderPath = 'files/New folder';
```

Here are the conditions that i want to prevent, For example user tries:

```
../../.././../../././../files/New folder
```

OR

```
../../.././../../././../files/New folder/../../././../.././
```

OR

```
./files/New folder/
```

Basically i need to extract the New folder from the URL thus i need the URL cleaned !

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

Tried the following but it only removes the Multiple slashes '../' and './' from the start of the URL.

```
var cleaned  = folderPath.replace(/^.+\.\//, '');
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
if someone can provide a function that cleans the url that will be much helpful.

```
files/New folder
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your expected output? `files/New folder`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes thats my expected output

Comment: Well krafted question with enough information to give a relevant answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a filter?

```js
var oneSlash = (str) => str.split("/").filter(
      word => word.match(/\w+/)
    ).join("/")

console.log(oneSlash(" ../../.././../../././../files/New folder"))

console.log(oneSlash("///../..///files/New folder///../"))

// this imaginary useless path ends up like the others

console.log(oneSlash("files/////New folder/"))
```

Comment: This is awesome. but only one case i can think it will fails when input is like `/../files///new folder/`

Comment: Sure but that useless path was not part of the spec :)

Comment: @mplungjan can you please provide a function i am not being able to use this

Comment: This answer is much better than others Works for most of the cases

Answer (score 1):

So here the idea is first using the regex i am taking out the match from the input string but it includes `//` extra which you also want to remove so in the callback function i removing those `//` also using replace on matched group.

I guess this (using replace twice) still can be improved i am trying to improve a bit more.

```js
function replaceDots(input){
  return input.replace(/^[./]+([^.]+)\/?.*/g, function(match,group){
    return group.replace(/(.*?)\/*$/, "$1")
  })
}

console.log(replaceDots(`../../.././../../././../files/New folder`))
console.log(replaceDots(`files/New folder`))
console.log(replaceDots(`../../.././../../././../files/New folder/../../././../.././`))
console.log(replaceDots(`///../..///files/New folder///../`))
```

Comment: Can you please update to clean something like this also `///../..///files/New folder///../`

Comment: And for the third one the trailing slash is still present

Comment: @MR_AMDEV you want to delete the last `/` also ? ok will update accordingly

Comment: Yes i want to remove the last slash also Thanks

Comment: Yikes - TWO  regex replace for the price of one ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to remove all unwanted text in your path,

```
\/?\.\.?\/|\/{2,}|\/\s*$
```

`\/?\.\.?\/` this removes all patterns of type `../` or `./` or `/../` and `\/{2,}` removes all occurrences of two or more `/` and `\/\s*` removes all trailing slashes in the path.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wixDbB/1)**

```js
console.log('../../.././../../././../files/New folder'.replace(/\/?\.\.?\/|\/{2,}|\/\s*$/g,''));
console.log('../../.././../../././../files/New folder/../../././../.././'.replace(/\/?\.\.?\/|\/{2,}|\/\s*$/g,''));
console.log('./files/New folder/'.replace(/\/?\.\.?\/|\/{2,}|\/\s*$/g,''));
console.log('///../..///files/New folder///../'.replace(/\/?\.\.?\/|\/{2,}|\/\s*$/g,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `/` preceded by `.` or `/` plus ending `/`:

```js
var folderPaths = [
  "../../.././../../././../files/New folder",
  "../../.././../../././../files/New folder/../../././../.././",
  "./files/New folder/"
];
var re = new RegExp('(?:[./]+)/|/$', 'g');

folderPaths.forEach(e => console.log(e.replace(re, "")));
```